# Kotlin for with different increment

Tags: java, for-loop, kotlin

Kotlin has the follow for

```
for (i in 0..10) {}
```

it is similar to Java

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
```

but how change the increment in kotlin to get something like it in java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2) {}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
for (i in 1..4 step 2) print(i) // prints "13"
```

See here: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html

Comment: yeah I'm reading the interloop section (http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) i do not think about "others" section

Comment: I did not know that word 'step' maybe because of it i do not found on google :/

Comment: @ademar111190 No problem. If you don't have any other questions, you can mark this resolved by accepting the answer.

Comment: yes. I'm going to do it, just waiting the minimum time, the question was so fool that was solved in less time than the minimum of stackoverflow